# IE 7 and 8 performance on modern web apps

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, asp.net-2.0

I'm currently developing a moderately large sized web app with ASP.NET 2.0 that uses a lot of jQuery/jQueryUI for things like tabs, modal dialogs, and general client-side coolness.  We've got it running on our test area now, but IE7 and IE8 are performing very poorly with all the page setup that needs to happen for the tabs and modal dialogs.  On one of our older laptops (Dell, 3 or 4 years old), it's approximately 3 to 5 seconds to load the page from the test server over our internal network (wireless), both the first time and on postbacks.  Firefox 5 takes 1 or 2 seconds on the same machine.  Running SunSpider on IE8 and FF5 confirms that FF5 is almost 18 times faster with javascript.  I know there's dispute about the real-world value of stuff like SunSpider, but that's a big gap no matter how you slice it.

My question is this:  how is classic IE (7 and 8) generally handled when developing web apps that involve a significant amount of javascript processing?  Is bad performance OK?  If so, to what degree?

My kneejerk reaction is to treat IE-classic as the exception.  It's going away ([Google apps will soon drop support](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html), and [IE9 is an automatic update for Windows Vista and 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/gg615599)), and cannot be considered part of the modern web as an application platform.  It needs to work because it's still a large portion of the browser share, but some small layout and performance issues are OK.  I've heard before that "[performance](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html) is a [feature](http://5by5.tv/buildanalyze/12)", but that can't be a reality for all users and platforms.

UPDATE, to clarify: this is for the general internet, not for an internal network at a company that's still running IE7 only.

Comment: Did you tried to identify where is a bottleneck? Any IE after IE6 is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer to this question is: "Who is your target user/demographic and what browsers are they using?"

If your app is for a large global bank and their employees, assume they are ALL running 4 year old Dells with Windows XP and IE6 with a 14" monitor.

If your app is for the public at large, then I say 'good riddance' to IE8 and below. You shouldn't have to accommodate a faulty platform at the expense of everyone else using a modern supported browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target client. If it's for an intranet and you can control what they'll use (Firefox or Chrome or IE9) then yes, you don't need to worry that much.  But if it's a general internet application then, like it or not, it should run fine in IE7 and IE8 as still about 50% of the people use it (in my case, it's more like 75% but that's my type of business).
You might want to use Firebug and check the connectivity tab, maybe use the pagespeed addon, etc. Sometimes it's not the code that's slow, but having lots of include files (CSS, javascript, etc). Try not to have too many includes.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing for a few years now with the jquery library. And the answer is IE 7 and 8 are slow compared to the current generation of browsers. Usually when we get to such a roadblock (working for a company that own and develop big portal site) we do try to optimize and rethink do we really need such a heavy thing. Also if you go to Yslow maximum on the other things you have a second or two more so your user experience is not affected much. Sadly IE is here to stay. You could try some progressive rendering, delay some non essential scripts or just cut features and eye candy. But for general purpose apps they are ok. If you give more details on the exact scripts you are struggling with we may be able to provide better advice.

Comment: I agree that IE as a browser is not going to go away, but the versions that were so much of a ball and chain to the web are going away.  IE9 is not perfect, but it's just as fast with javascript as anything else these days.  I'd argue that IE7 and IE8 are on their way out.